# Ошибка при попытке запуска функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Необходимо сделать программу:
Выводит вопрос, если число введенное больше 5, выводит ответ "Все нормально, можно начинать взлом", если меньше 5 "Пива недостаточно.". Если введены буквы или что-то другое пишет "Введите число!" и снова просит "Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: ".
И после того как вывело "Все нормально, можно начинать взлом" или "Пива недостаточно.", программа снова запускается и просит ввести "Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: " и так по кругу.

```
def x():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: '))
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print('Введите число!')
if x >= 5:
    print('Все нормально, можно начинать взлом')
else:
    print('Пива недостаточно.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def x():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: '))
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print('Введите число!')
if x() > 5:
    print('Все нормально, можно начинать')
else:
    print('Пива недостаточно.')
```

Comment: И после того как вывело "Все нормально, можно начинать взлом" или "Пива недостаточно.", программа снова запускается и просит ввести "Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: " и так по кругу. " Это как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    def x():
        try:
            x = int(input('Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: '))
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print('Введите число!')
    if x() >= 5:
        print('Все нормально, можно начинать')
    else:
        print('Пива недостаточно.')
```

Comment: У вас не там цикл был. Если вся функция должна работать бесконечное количество раз, то она вся целиком помещается внутрь бесконечного цикла.

Comment: В таком виде вылазит ошибка если ввести букву.

Answer (score 0):

В таком виде работает как надо. Всем спасибо!

```
while True:
    def x():
        while True:
            try:
                x = int(input('Введи, сколько у вас литров пива: '))
                return x
            except ValueError:
                print('Введите число!')
    if x() >= 5:
        print('Все нормально, можно начинать')
    else:
        print('Пива недостаточно.')
```